# How to send a custom preview with messages using python telegram bot?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

[image]I have been trying to produce a way to show a message with a preview like the one in the image.
I want to use the same idea to send text messages with some writing preview.
Is this possible with python telegram bot

I tried to do it with the send_message but i didn't know how

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.